# Sailsjs: set a cookie for all website visitors

Tags: cookies, sails.js, ejs

I have a website build on sailsjs. I'm looking to do an A/B test on a CTA used throughout the site.... and thought the easiest way to accomplish this would be to write a 1 or 0 to a cookie. Users with 1 get version A of the CTA; users with 2 get version B. Pretty simple.

Where I'm having trouble is writing the cookie for all users -- regardless of which page they land on first. I see how I can easily do this from a controller, but that would only write the cookie for users visiting that particular page... and I don't want to duplicate this code in each and every controller on the site.

Does anyone have any recommendations on the right approach for how I'm trying to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this in Sails.  You'll often see something like this done in a [policy](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies), but best practice is to use policies purely for access control.  Another way would be to use [custom middleware](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/middleware), but that's probably overkill for your case.  I'd recommend a [custom hook](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks), which is easy to configure (and re-use in different apps):

```js
// api/hooks/add-cookie.js
module.exports = function addCookie(sails) {

  return {

    // Add some routes to the app.
    routes: {

      // Add these routes _before_ anything defined in `config/routes.js`.
      before: {

        // Add a route that will match everything (using skipAssets to...skip assets!)
        '/*': {
          fn: function(req, res, next) {

            // Set the cookie.
            res.cookie('myCookie', 123);

            // Continue with the request.
            return next();

          },
          skipAssets: true
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks sgress454. That's exactly what I was looking for.